# why the Application class (Android) doesn't save the instance objects ?

Tags: android

In my android project I implement MainApplication Class that extends Application:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
        private City city; 

public City getCity(){
return city;
}
}
```

and in the splash screen activity I send http request and then set the city object.

I implement getCity method in activity number one and then in activity number tow.
the problem some times I get NullPointerException in Activity number tow(city = null),although the city wasn't null in activity number one.

what is happening ? and How could I solve the problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The object is null because the activity one end your life-cicle. A Singleton can  solve your problem maybe.

Comment: what do you mean by "Singleton can solve your problem" I am using singleton, notice I extends Application class !

Comment: try to chance to private static City city

Comment: I think it is a good idea ,thank you! but the application class are declared just one time, so what the static will add ?